# How to scan all @Bean or @Component of Specific Type

Tags: spring-boot

I am playing with Spring boot and trying to create a library.

As part of that, I have an interface.

```
interface Dummy {
    String doSomething(String input);
}
```

There could be multiple implementations.

```
public class DummyImplA implements Dummy {}
public class DummyImplB implements Dummy {}
public class DummyImplC implements Dummy {}
```

I would like to look for all the implementations exposed as Beans `@Bean` or `@Component`
and invoke the doSomething method automatically when the app starts.

Does spring provide any option for scanning for beans of specific type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question you'd like to get all beans of specific type.
There are lot of way to do that.

**Option 1 : Autowire a list of Dummy in a spring component**

```
@Component
public class SpringComponent {

  private List<Dummy> listDummy;
  public  SpringComponent (List<Dummy> list) {
   listDummy = list;
  }      
  //In a method, iterate on listDummy and call doSomething method.
  public void callDoSomething() {
     for(Dummy d : listDummy) {
        d.doSomething();
     }
  }
}
```

**Option 2 : Autowire a map of Dummy in a spring component**

```
@Component
public class SpringComponent {
    private final Map<String, Dummy> mapDummies;
    public SpringComponent(Map<String, Dummy> mapD) {
        mapDummies = mapD;
    }
    public void callDoSomething() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Dummy> entry : mapDummies.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 3 : Autowire applicationContext and get all bean of type Dummy from it**
There are several way to get or autowire applicationContext.

```
@Component
public class SpringComponent {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public SpringComponent(ConfigurableApplicationContext ac) {
        applicationContext = ac;
    }
    public void getBeanOfDummy() {
          Map <String, Dummy> mapDummies = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Dummy.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Dummy> entry : mapDummies.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a Dummy<T> , Can I get the T type?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. Can you give me more detail